# Capture and move a unique_ptr in a c++14 lambda expression

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, c++14

I am capturing a unique_ptr in a lambda expression this way:

```
auto str = make_unique<string>("my string");
auto lambda = [ capturedStr = std::move(str) ] {
   cout << *capturedStr.get() << endl;
};
lambda();
```

It works great until I try to move `capturedStr` to another unique_ptr. For instance, the following is not working:

```
auto str = make_unique<string>("my string");
auto lambda = [ capturedStr = std::move(str) ] {
    cout << *capturedStr.get() << endl;
    auto str2 = std::move(capturedStr); // <--- Not working, why?
};
lambda();
```

Here is the output from the compiler:

```
.../test/main.cpp:11:14: error: call to implicitly-deleted copy
constructor of 'std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::basic_string<char>,
std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::basic_string<char> > >'
        auto str2 = std::move(capturedStr);
             ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ../include/c++/v1/memory:2510:31: note: copy constructor is implicitly
deleted because 'unique_ptr<std::__1::basic_string<char>,
std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::basic_string<char> > >' has a
user-declared move constructor
    _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY unique_ptr(unique_ptr&& __u) _NOEXCEPT
                              ^ 1 error generated.
```

Why isn't it possible to move `capturedStr`?

Comment: Lambdas' `operator ()` is `const` unless it's declared `mutable`, and you can't move from a `const` object.

Comment: Thanks @T.C., can you write an answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 74, accepted):

The `operator ()` of a lambda is `const` by default, and you can't move from a `const` object.

Declare it `mutable` if you want to modify the captured variables.

```
auto lambda = [ capturedStr = std::move(str) ] () mutable {
//                                             ^^^^^^^^^^
    cout << *capturedStr.get() << endl;
    auto str2 = std::move(capturedStr);
};
```

Comment: I thought you weren't gonna post :) +1

Answer (score 11):

```
auto lambda = [ capturedStr = std::move(str) ] {
   cout << *capturedStr.get() << endl;
   auto str2 = std::move(capturedStr); // <--- Not working, why?
};
```

To give more detail, the compiler is effectively making this transformation:

```
class NameUpToCompiler
{
    unique_ptr<string> capturedStr;  // initialized from move assignment in lambda capture expression

    void operator()() const
    {
        cout << *capturedStr.get() << endl;
        auto str2 = std::move(capturedStr);  // move will alter member 'captureStr' but can't because of const member function.
    }
}
```

The use of `mutable` on the lambda will remove the `const` from the `operator()` member function, therefore allowing the members to be altered.

Answer (score 6):

To make the advice more explicit: add `mutable`: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a19897451b82cbbb

```
#include <memory>

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<int> pi(new int(42));

    auto ll = [ capturedInt = std::move(pi) ] () mutable { };
}
```